# Setting up basic game and debugging fundamental problems

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging

I have a little problem trying to create a simple snake game in a basic tile engine. I have never worked with C# or Windows Forms and currently in a learning stage. I'd appreciate any help i get from here.

```
        int[,] level = {
                               { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 },
                               { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 },
                               { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 },
                               { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 },
                               { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 },
                               { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 },
                           };
```

Currently, all the tiles are empty thus off. If i want to lets say add the image, all i have to do is turn 0 to 1. My goal is to turn 0 to 1 with the arrow keys from keyboard.

```
private void tmrMov_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_objPosition == Position.Right) 
        {

            if(_x<6 && _x>=0)
            _x += 1;

         }
        .
        .
        .
         //and so on
        .
        .
        .

        Invalidate();
    }
```

With this, i am trying to turn 0 to 1 through arrow keys but it currently does not work.

```
        public Form1()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            _x = rand.Next(0,5 + 1);
            _y = rand.Next(0, 5 + 1);
            _k = 1;
            level[_x, _y] = _k;
            _objPosition = Position.Right;
    }
```

This is how i am calling the above array...

Please let me know what i am doing wrong. I know i have to eventually start over or pick up another project to work on but i want to at least know that i was not completely wrong.

I am attaching the complete project since it's not long to read...
http://www.mediafire.com/?hz3h2job28y9lfb

EDIT:
This question is also posted here since one of the answers on stackexchange suggested to post here for debugging questions: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/simple-gameproblem-with-key-mapping

Feel free to delete one of the other but not both!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarification in what i am trying to accomplish. I believe the idea should be simple to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your snake, you should put `0` in its previous location (since for now it is only on cell long), calculate the new location, and put `1` in the new location. So your timer's tick hanlder could look like this:

```
private void tmrMov_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    level[_x, _y] = 0;
    //...
    // other stuff to calculate new location based on Position

    level[_x, _y] = 1;

    Invalidate();
}
```

Also adding PictureBoxes in the `Paint` event is completely wrong. You should draw the board, using various methods of the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class. It seems that you wanted to do that, but why did you give it up?

There is a lot to say about your code. Here are a few of them:

1. Instead of using the magic number `6` everywhere for the board width or height, put the size of the board in varaibles and use them everywhere. This way you can easily change the board size without affecting the whole source code (or just forgetting to update a sinlge `6` and introduce a hard-to-find bug).
2. Instead of loading the image everytime from file (commented code in `panel1_Paint`), load the image once, resize it if required, and keep it in a field. Use it everytime required. This enhances the performance dramatically.
3. Use [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx) to load an image form file.
4. You never want your snake to go out of the board, so when you wnat to move the snake right (for example), you can increment the `_x` only when `_x < _boardWidth-1`. You know waht I mean when I say `_boardWidth`, don't you? :-)
5. You should paint the whole board in the `Paint` event. No just a single cell. `Paint` event is called whenever your form needs to be draw, not just when you call the `Invalidate` method.
6. You have an enumeration called `Position`. It should be actually `Direction`.

Happy learning.

Comment: Thank you for the throughput. I will look into your bullet points as well.

Comment: The fact that some of the points you mentioned i already tried with no luck but i hope now that i have something to stare at i will more or less improve it.

Comment: Ok so now i run into scopping problem now that i closely followed all your guidlines i have problem with `level[_x, _y] = 0;` and `level[_x, _y] = _k;`

Comment: Well, what is the problem? Please ask another question for that. Try to ask a good question :-) Also you should accept the answers if they are helpful. Please read [faq] for more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169578/basic-image-refresh-issue-through-array-manipulation